# Polymorphic addition in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, math, data-structures

I am trying to create a program that adds a polymorphic number that are organized in Rows and columns, so hopefully  if you take a look at the arrays I have created you will get an idea of what I am trying to do, but think of it as this way you have 3 arrays `A`, `B`, `C` and I am trying to calculate `A+B=C`.

But I don't get anything but foolishness, I need help because I know so little about data structures:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i,j,A[10][10],B[10][10],C[10][10], nf, nc;
   cout<<"#Rows: "<<endl;
   cin>>nf;
   cout<<"#Columns: "<<endl;
   cin>>nc;


   //For the A part
   for(int i=0; i<=nf;i++){
      cout<<"Enter the row Number  # "<<i;
      for(int j= 0; j<=nc;j++){
         cout<<"Enter Column Column#"<<j<<endl;;  
         cin>>A[i][j];
   }}

   //For the B part     
   for(int i=0; i<=nf;i++){
      cout<<"Enter Row # "<<i<<endl;

      for(int j= 0; j<=nc;j++){
         cout<<"Enter Column# "<<j<<endl;  
         cin>>B[i][j];
   }}


   //Calculation              
   for(int i=0; i<nf;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<nc;j++)
         C[i][j]= A[i][j]+ B[i][j];  


   //output     
   for(int i=0; i<nf;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<nc;j++)
          cout<<C[i][j];  

   system("PAUSE");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The input can only be 0-9 , you know that right ?

Comment: When you ask for the data input you use `i <= nf` as the condition in the `for` loop, but in the output you use `i < nf`.  The input and output are different sizes.  If you still find you have garbage, check that your input is as expected by printing `A` and `B`, not just `C`.

Comment: I believe you mean "matrix addition" rather than "polymorphic addition".

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your cells to 0. else they will contain junk value and that will be used for addition. You can do it by initialization or using a loop.

```
int main()
{
int nf, nc, A[10][10]={0}, B[10][10]={0}, C[10][10]={0};


}
```

You have unused variables i and j. they are not a reason for erroneous output but still avoid it.

you can find a simplified corrected form of your program [here](http://ideone.com/MwONG#view_edit_box) (Array Bounds have also been corrected)

```
 for(int i=0; i<nf;i++)    
    for(int j= 0; j<nc;j++)
```

these loops are used in both input and output

Answer (score 0):

the bounds in you'r input *for* loops i guess is not what you want it to be  or atleast it is not consistent with the calculation loop

```
for(int j= 0; j<=nc;j++)  vs  for(int j= 0; j<nc;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be your response:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i,j,A[10][10],B[10][10],C[10][10], nr, nc;
cout<<"#Rows: "<<endl;
cin>>nr;
cout<<"#Columns: "<<endl;
cin>>nc;


//For the A part
for(int i=0; i<nr;i++){
    for(int j= 0; j<nc;j++){
        cout<<"Enter the A["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
        cin>>A[i][j];
    }
}

//For the B part     
for(int i=0; i<nr;i++){
    for(int j= 0; j<nc;j++){
        cout<<"Enter the B["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
        cin>>B[i][j];
    }
}


//Calculation              
for(int i=0; i<nr;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<nc;j++)
        C[i][j]= A[i][j]+ B[i][j];


//output     
for(int i=0; i<nr;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<nc;j++)
        cout<<C[i][j];

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont complicate things with many cout statements.

```
cout<<"Enter a["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : ";
cin>>a[i][j];
```

`i = 0` to `nf` means you are reading `nf+1` elements. So there is array out of bound. Be careful with `i<nf` and `i<=nf`.